# Ramification of Primes in Cyclotomic Extensions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose we have cyclotomic fields $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{ab}), (a,b)=1, \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{a}), \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{b}).$

Now, I am wondering about a few things:

- What is the connection between the ramification of
  primes in those extensions? In particular, I encountered the fact
  that $$e_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{a}),
     \mathbb{Q}}(p)=e_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{ab}), \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{b})}(p),
     $$ where $e$ is the ramification index, and also
  $$e_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{b}), \mathbb{Q}}(p)=e_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{ab}),
     \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{a})}(p). $$ I don't understand why those facts would
  be true.
  (I understand that ramification is multiplicative in towers, but I am not sure why does it have to be just like this.)
- One more thing that I am interested in is, if we have (p,a)=1, does
  that necessarily mean that $e_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{a}),
     \mathbb{Q}}(p)=1?$ If yes, why so?

Comment: It because if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, the corresponding cyclotomic extensions are arithmetically disjoint, that is linearly disjoint and having coprime discriminants.

Comment: Also what do you mean exactly with $e_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{ab}), \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{b})}(p)$ given that in most cases $(p)$ is not a prime ideal of $O_{ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{b})}$ ?